# Select the target application does not appear in vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, extendscript

I use vscode a lot to write scripts for Adobe applications, and in recent days when I opened vscode, the button with the yellow inscription "Select the target application" that appears in the status bar at the bottom of the vscode window suddenly disappeared, and in its place [another button appeared with the inscription "Eval in Adobe"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsTcg.jpg).

I tried to Google it, I tried to check in the plugin settings if there is a setting that causes this, and also I tried to install previous versions of the plugin, but to no avail.

Please enlighten my eyes and explain to me how to get it back.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a way to get it back, but it should give you the same functionality as before.

The new 'Eval in Adobe' button, after clicking, should give a dropdown of all possible Adobe Apps that you can run your program in.

Alternatively you can go into the Debug panel and click 'Run and Debug'. Then select 'Extendscript' then 'Attach'. At that point it will give you the same Adobe App selection choice.

The button will change to orange and say 'Eval in Adobe (Program Name Here)'. You can then use it to immediately enter debug without having to reselect your target application.

Comment: The problem is that **it doesn't give the same functionality**, in the current state I have to click **every time** on 'Eval in Adobe' > Select Host Application > Select ExtendScript Engine.
When had the 'Select the target application' option, I only had to select the first time every time I opened vscode, and it would remember my selection until I closed vscode.

Comment: Oh sorry I think I misunderstood. When go through 'Run and Debug' in the debug panel, you can select 'Attach' instead of 'Launch'. That will keep you tied to whatever application you want. Then the button will change to orange and you can rerun it any time.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: As I mentioned, go to the Debug Panel in VSCode. Select Run and Debug. Select Extendscript. It will then give you the option Launch or Attach. Select Attach, then pick the Adobe App youre working with from the dropdown. You'll know it worked when the bottom UI turns orange.

Comment: And how do I run a certain script on the application I selected?

Comment: Just make sure you have your script open as the main page in vscode. Oh I forgot to mention, the Adobe app needs to be open in the background already.

Comment: I did not understand. What do I need to click to run the script on the app?